# Choose First match from an XPath

Tags: xpath

The XPath (bookstore/book/title|bookstore/book/author) selects title, author if both of them exist

How can I select just the first match of these two and not both, and get this value for all the 'book' nodes in the document

(bookstore/book/title|bookstore/book/author)[1]  limits the result to just the first 'title' in the first book.But I need to be able to get results from other book nodes in the document

Comment: Oh wait I think I understand now ... you want to select, with one XPath expression, a node-set of all the first-of-title-or-author elements of all the book elements in the document. Right?

Comment: P.S. XPath has a boolean `or` operator, and a node-set union operator (`|`). They are not the same thing.

Comment: The question of whether you have XPath 1.0 or 2.0 becomes critical here. If you have 2.0, it's possible; otherwise, I don't think so.

Comment: BTW it will be quite a bit easier to be sure of the question and to help you if you provide example XML input and desired output of the XPath expression.

Comment: hi, The xml input that i was trying the expression can be found at http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/tryit.asp?filename=try_xpath_select_cdnodes,  this tutorial says it is using xpath 2.0

Comment: agree with your first comment,I need a node-set of all the first-of-title-or-author elements of all the book elements in the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that by 'first' you mean 'first in document order', not 'first referenced in my XPath expression.'

In XPath 2.0, you can say

```
bookstore/book/((title|author)[1])
```

If you only have XPath 1.0, let us know and we can proceed from there. Also let us know something of the broader environment (XSLT? XQuery? Javascript?) because some of this may have to be done outside of XPath.

Update: I just tested this, using [Simple Online XPath Tester](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath) with XPath 2.0. Given the following XML input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>

<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

and the XPath expression

```
/bookstore/book/((title|author)[1])
```

I get the following output, which appears to be what you asked for:

```
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
```

## For XPath 1.0

If you don't have XPath 2.0, as I suspect you don't, and you still want to do it all in XPath, here's what I would do:

```
/bookstore/book/title[1] | /bookstore/book[not(title)]/author[1]
```

What does this do? It gives the (first) title of each book that has a title, as well as the (first) author of each book that doesn't have a title.

This expression is not *quite* as general as what you asked for: it assumes that `<title>` comes before `<author>` when it exists, as it does in your sample data. If your data has author before title, then the above expression will still prefer title despite the order.

If you really need the *first* of the two regardless of whether it's author or title, try

```
/bookstore/book/title[1][not(preceding-sibling::author)] |
  /bookstore/book/author[1][not(preceding-sibling::title)]
```

Comment: the above expression does not give any results back, i am going to use this xpath in a java program, i ideally need all the interpretation to be done via xpath.

Comment: i have tried /bookstore/book/((title|author)[1]), and this returns just the first title and ignores the other title elements.

Comment: @user1373231: Now that you've divulged the input XML... yes, putting a `/` on the beginning is safer than not, depending on the context node you started from.

Comment: @user1373231: I edited my answer to show test results with XPath 2.0. Maybe if you show some of your code, we can tell whether you have XPath 1.0 or 2.0. If 1.0, you will probably have to do some of the processing in Java.

Comment: @user1373231: I added an XPath 1.0 solution above (actually two). I tested them, again using the online Simple XPath Tester and the XML I showed above. They work ask expected.

Comment: thankyou very much for this, for my requirement, the order in the document is not priority but the 'title' element itself, i couldnt figure out which xpath was used in our code as some of the data parsing code is in a jar which i dont have source for.But i think the information you have given is what I was looking for , thankyou